# Input String not in correct format error, only when ID column Visible Property is set to false

Tags: asp.net, gridview

My page has a GridView for managing Factory Plants.  I'm able to successfully edit the data in the Grid by clicking the edit link and then saving my changes upon clicking the update link. I want the ID column of the Grid to be hidden from the user, so I added the Visible Property to the Plant_ID column of the Grid and set it to false, the column is hidden, but I get an error: "Input string was not in a correct format" upon hitting the update link.

This is my Grid and SQL data Source:

```
<asp:GridView  ID="GridPlants" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Plant_ID" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="7" 
                        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
                        BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="2" CssClass="datatable" GridLines="None" 
                        ShowFooter="True" SortedAscendingCellStyle-CssClass="sortasc" OnSorting="gvPlant_Sorting" 
                        SortedAscendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="sortasc" 
                        SortedDescendingCellStyle-CssClass="sortdesc" 
                        SortedDescendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="sortdesc" 
                           OnRowCancelingEdit="GridPlants_RowCancelingEdit" 
                        OnRowEditing="GridPlants_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridPlants_RowUpdating" OnPageIndexChanging="gvPlants_PageIndexChanging" 
                        >
                        <EditRowStyle />
                        <PagerStyle CssClass="pager-row" />
                        <RowStyle CssClass="row" />
                        <Columns>
                             <asp:BoundField DataField="Plant_ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Plant_ID" Visible="false" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Plant Name" SortExpression="Plant_Name">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Txtplant" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Plant_Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Plant_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Plant Code" SortExpression="Plant_code">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Txtcode" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Plant_code") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Plant_code") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Txtaddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Txtcity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("City") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("City") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="State" SortExpression="State">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Txtstate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("State") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("State") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Zip" SortExpression="Zip">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Txtzip" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Zip") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Zip") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Plant Email" SortExpression="Plant_Email">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Txtemail" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Plant_Email") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Plant_Email") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" SortExpression="Active">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="Chkactive" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("Active") %>' 
                                        Enabled="false" />
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("Active") %>' 
                                        Enabled="false" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="UpdateBy" HeaderText="Update By" 
                                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="UpdateBy" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="UpdateDate" HeaderText="Update Date" ReadOnly="True" 
                                SortExpression="UpdateDate" />
                        </Columns>
                       <%-- <PagerSettings FirstPageText="«" LastPageText="»" Mode="NumericFirstLast" 
                            PageButtonCount="7" />--%>
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle CssClass="sortasc" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortasc" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle CssClass="sortdesc" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortdesc" />
                    </asp:GridView>

                    <asp:SqlDataSource  ID="PlantDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ShipmentNotification %>"
                SelectCommand="select Plant_ID, Plant_Name, Plant_code, Address, City, State, Zip, Plant_Email, Active, UpdateDate, UpdateBy from Plant order by plant_code">
                 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This is my Update function:

```
 Protected Sub GridPlants_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GridPlants.RowUpdating
        Dim Editrow As GridViewRow = GridPlants.Rows(e.RowIndex)



Dim PlantId As String = GridPlants.DataKeys(e.RowIndex)("Plant_ID")
            Dim textplant As TextBox = Editrow.FindControl("txtplant")
            Dim textcode As TextBox = Editrow.FindControl("txtcode")
            Dim checkbox As CheckBox = Editrow.FindControl("chkactive")
            Dim address As TextBox = Editrow.FindControl("txtaddress")
            Dim city As TextBox = Editrow.FindControl("txtcity")
            Dim state As TextBox = Editrow.FindControl("txtstate")
            Dim zip As TextBox = Editrow.FindControl("txtzip")
            Dim email As TextBox = Editrow.FindControl("txtemail")

    'I get an error on the following line:
            DL.AddUpdatePlants("Admin", "Edit", Editrow.Cells(1).Text, textplant.Text, textcode.Text, address.Text, city.Text, state.Text, zip.Text, email.Text, checkbox.Checked)
            'CType(Editrow.Cells(2).Controls(0), TextBox)).
            GridPlants.EditIndex = -1
            BindData()


        End Sub
```

...Snippet of the stored procedure:

```
Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand("SavePlantDetails", myConnection)
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure


            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@editType", addupdate)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Plant_ID", plant_id)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Plant_Name", name)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Plant_code", code)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", city)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", state)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zip", zip)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", active)
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

            myConnection.Close()
```

...I'm wondering if by hiding the Plant_ID field, is that throwing off how I have my columns arranged? Could I get some help with this issue please?  I only get the error after added the Visible property to the Plant_ID column and setting it to True. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `Editrow.Cells(1).Text` supposed to contains your plant id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value for `Editrow.Cells(1).Text` may not be coming up with visible false.

You can use the DataKeyNames property of the grid view to retrive this value.

set it as follows:

```
<asp:GridView  ID="GridPlants" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Plant_ID" /> // rest of gridview markup
```

retrieve it as follows:

```
Dim PlantId as String = GridPlants.DataKeys(e.RowIndex)("Plant_ID")
```

and use this in your update function.

Comment: I tried the recommendation, but I still get the same error.   Please let me know if you have any other suggestions. I applied the recommended edits to the code provided above.

Comment: i don't see PlantId being used in the line DL.AddUpdatePlants("Admin", "Edit", Editrow.Cells(1).Text..  you need to replace Editrow.Cells(1).Text with the plant id.. on that note, what does GridPlants.DataKeys(e.RowIndex) show? put a breakpoint and let us know.. your plantid should be in there

Comment: My mistake, as you pointed out, I left out PlantID, and yes when I placed a break point at GridPlants.DataKeys(e.RowIndex) - it contained the Plant ID - Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**The Concept:**

```
Editrow.Cells(1).Text
```

or in General: 
`rows.Cells(index).Text` can ONLY be used to read data from a `<asp:BoundField>` field.

If you have TemplateFields as in `<ItemTemplate>` and `<EditItemTemplate>`, You must use the `FindControl()`  method.

Here you have set `AutoGenerateEditButton="true"`, thus your first Column ( Cell Zero  obviously ) will contain the edit buttons actually. Starting with 2nd Column ( Cell 1) will be your Fields as you defined in your GridView Markup.

**CASE I::**

When you have set `Visible="true"` for your first `<asp:BoundField>` field, then Cells(1).Text actually refers to the Text inside Your Bound Field which is correct.

**CASE II::**

However, when you set `Visible="false"` for your first `<asp:BoundField>` field, then `Cells(1).Text` NO more refers to the first `BoundField`, but actually it's the next   `TemplateField`:  `Plant_Name`. The Data/Text in case of `<asp:TemplateField>` Column isn't inside the `Cells` but inside the Controls placed in these TemplateFields. This is the reason you get an error.